# Which way to save into an other index on elasticsearh the result of some operation make during indexation

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, analyzer

I need to save some data which be the result of some operation make during indexation operation (analyzer or other way) into an other elasticsearch index. For example, i've got :

- Doc 1.1; time 2s
- Doc 1.2; time 5s
- Doc 2.1; time 3s
- Doc 2.2; time 7s

I need to save the result of 1.1 - 1.2 for example (here the result is 2 - 5 => 3), in other index (for performance). Of course this is a simplification, there are some other field. But what is the best manner for do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to wrap all those indexation in your own code.
Just index your docs, and then, if this is successfull, compute the others doc from them or from the index response and index them in your second index.

I am not sure I undestood the question, but if that was  it, I'm pretty sure (though I could be wrong) that ES cannot do those seconds indexations by itself, no matter how magical it is.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, and yes apparently you understand my master trouble that was the "seconds indexations". So, I must develop a custom java plugin for do this I think. There is a "hook" to catch a succefull indexation step?

Comment: Here, we are writing our own application rather than a plugin, so I wouldn't know. But If you write a small program for this, you have the IndexResponse class you can get in response of an indexation. By bulk, you can iterate on the BulkItemResponses. For a Plugin, however, maybe you can try your luck asking on the mailing list. Many users there that are far more experienced than I am